# Mysql inserting from select statement only inserting zeroes

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert a new row in a table with count numbers from select statements from different tables. When I run the following, it creates the row but inserts 0 for the two fields with the select statements (instead of values 1047 and 8 that I get when I run the select statements individually) . I tried putting the select statements inside the insert statement as well but that was throwing errors. Any help on where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
select count(*) from research.Neuro_Recruited_MG as letters_sent;
select count(*) from research.neuro_subject_log s where s.enrolled like 'PS' as pending_screening;
insert into neuro_stats (id, letters_sent, pending_screening)
values (3, 'letters_sent','pending_screening’)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running three separate statements. The first two (the SELECTs) execute, but starting the next one discards the one before it.

Try something like this instead:

```
insert into neuro_stats 
  (id, letters_sent, pending_screening)
values 
  (3, 
   (select count(*) from research.Neuro_Recruited_MG),
   (select count(*) from research.neuro_subject_log s where s.enrolled like 'PS'));
```

Comment: This is one of the things I tried initially, and get this error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from research.Neuro_Recruited_MG, select count(*) from resear' at line 5

Comment: Note: It does work if I add quotes around the select statements, but that still updates the table with the 0's.

Comment: Yep. I missed some parentheses. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try, assuming id is auto_increment.

```
insert neuro_stats(letters_sent, pending_screening)
select sum(count_letters_sent), sum(count_pending_Screening)
from (
  select count(*) as count_letters_sent, 0 as count_pending_screening) 
  from research.neuro_recruited_MG
  UNION
  select 0 as count_letters_sent, count(*) as count_pending_screening
  from reserach.neuro_subject_log as s
  where s.enrolled like '%PS%'
) as xcount;
```

may be your like 'PS' needs the wildcard character % before and/or after your 'PS' in fact of a search like "beginning", "containing" or "ending" with 'PS'

Comment: Thanks! This solution is not working for me, seems like the union is throwing an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from research.neuro_recruited_MG UNION select 0 as count_letters_sent, count(*) as co' at line 5

Comment: Please execute no SQL-Statements without checking the syntax! Please remove the last ')' on line 4 and it runs, sorry. tried on MySQL 5.5.16